# Should I load html file with data or load html and then request data (with AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, html, user-experience, software-design

When creating a html file inside of a XAMP software system, I use to load in the first place the data from PHP that is critical to use the web page (for example, saving the user id in javascript to make AJAX requests to server) and then, after showing the body to the user, load irrelevant data for execution, but useful for the user (for example, a table with the last bought products of the user) from server with AJAX. That's it: first show html file to user and then ask for the remaining data to server.

I found this is maybe some kind of silly, because you could show all the html file with the data loaded from PHP, Perl, whatever.

But here is the point: is one option more correct than the other one?

I think that, maybe, the first option will be more user experience oriented (because, the user has the feeling of fast loading, he watch the html file early because he doesn't have to wait to load php data too before getting the html file). I read somewhere that javascript (and html) is oriented to UI, that's why you shouldn't, for exaple, block the UI with semaphores to wait an async task to be completed.

But maybe someone of you guys could give me a reasoning to be using the second option (load first PHP data and then show html) instead of using the first one; well done software is good software.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have everything you need, for building a page at first request, by all means, do it all at once.  There is no reason to keep your page busy by first loading the page, then keep the user waiting while you make an ajax request and process the results.

Comment: @Bindrid It's depend on page loading time, right? For 'heavy' pages you can load a minimal code and load asynchronously other contents. Anyway, it's depends on your needs imho

Comment: @mickdev, yes.  I use tabs and do not load them until the use clicks on them to save a lot of up front loading.  And, because I have so many select boxes on my interface, they do not get loaded until the user clicks on them. All loaded on demand with ajax

Comment: Maybe I shoud mentioned that the XAMP software system that I am suggesting is RESTfull. So maybe it is more comprehensible in that case to load data with AJAX instead of PHP due to fact that any app developed will load/write data in the same way (first show UI elements and then load data from server, in android for example, you first have the UI in a xml file and only need to load remaining data from server). Homogenize the way of doing the same task is design-useful or maybe it is some kind of twisted and useless?